# InkToolBarCustomPenButtons look incorrect when app is ran on other devices

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp

I have an `InkToolbar` with `InkToolBarCustomPenButton`s, when I run the program on my computer it looks correct (photo 1). When users download this app off the Microsoft Store it looks incorrect (photo 2).

[image: Custom pen buttons look correct]

[image: Custom pen buttons look incorrect]

The `InkToolbarCustomPenButton`s are created programmatically according to the following code:

```cs
internal class CustomPenButton : InkToolbarCustomPenButton
    {
        public CustomPen Pen;

        private Grid iconGrid = new Grid();
        private FontIcon penBase = new FontIcon() { FontFamily = new FontFamily("Segoe Fluent Icons"), FontSize=16 };
        private FontIcon penFill = new FontIcon() { FontFamily = new FontFamily("Segoe Fluent Icons"), FontSize=16 };

        public CustomPenButton(CustomPen pen)
        {
            this.Pen = pen;
            CustomPen = pen;
            LoadPenData(pen.Data);
            pen.Data.Changed += (e, a) => LoadPenData(pen.Data);

            ConfigurationContent = new PenConfiguration(this);

            RegisterPropertyChangedCallback(PaletteProperty, (sender, dp) =>
            {
                Palette.Add(new SolidColorBrush(pen.Data.DefaultColor));
                SelectedBrushIndex = Palette.Count - 1;
            });

            Binding b = new Binding() { Path = new PropertyPath("SelectedBrush"), Mode = BindingMode.OneWay, Source = this };
            penFill.SetBinding(FontIcon.ForegroundProperty, b);

            iconGrid.Children.Add(penFill);
            iconGrid.Children.Add(penBase);

            Content = iconGrid;
        }

        private void LoadPenData(PenData data)
        {
            MinStrokeWidth = data.MinimumStroke;
            SelectedStrokeWidth = data.StrokeSize;
            MaxStrokeWidth = data.MaximumStroke;
            switch (data.PenType)
            {
                case PenType.Pencil:
                    penBase.Glyph = "\uED63";
                    penFill.Glyph = "\uF0C6";
                    break;
                case PenType.Calligraphy:
                    penBase.Glyph = "\uEDFB";
                    penFill.Glyph = "\uF0C7";
                    break;
                case PenType.Highlighter:
                    penBase.Glyph = "\uE193";
                    penFill.Glyph = "\uE891";
                    break;
                case PenType.Ballpoint:
                    penBase.Glyph = "\uE76D";
                    penFill.Glyph = "\uE88F";
                    break;
            }
        }

    }
```

Comment: Have you checked the system version of users? It will be better if you can reproduce the same problem on your other computers, then you can check the difference between the two computers.